# disable OnNavigatedTo when app resume

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigateuri

I wonder if its possible to disable the OnNavigatedTo event in windows phone application.
Why I would like to do this is beacuse when I navigate in the app everything works as I want.

But when I go to the homescreen and back to the application when it resumes it does OnNavigatedTo and I only want that to be fired as long as you navigate between pages in the application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a `static` `Boolean` flag as `false`, when u going out from the `application` (homescreen `OnBackKeyPress`) & set it as `true` when app starts(homescreen `OnNavigatedTo`).
now check this flag on every `OnNavigatedTo` of pages wherever u need.

Comment: Now I did it like this: **Boolean backnav = false;**, then for OnNavigatedTo I set it as true **backnav = true** have i understand it correct? But what happens when i press the **homebutton**

Comment: @RobinM you can't disable or change the behaviour of the Home button, it will always suspend the current app and return the user to the Start Menu.

Comment: I dont want to change it. I just want the OnNavigatedTo not to fire when you resume the app, so there is no protected ovveride for home button